# How to load matlab cell matrix of varied size into python

Tags: python, matlab

I need to load a cell array generated in `Matlab` into `Python`. Each element in the cell is 2D matrix, and varies in the matrix size.

I tried both `scipy.io.loadmat` and also `mat2py.loadmat`, both cannot give desired results (e.g., a list of `numpy` arrays). With the former, the resulting data is of `object` type, and the latter gives a list but does not maintain the shape of array elements in the cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in matlab, save the data as JSON using **JSONLab**: https://github.com/fangq/jsonlab
or save the data as HDF5 using **EasyH5**: https://github.com/fangq/easyh5

then, open python, import the json file using

```
import json
with open('mydata.json', 'r') as fid:
   data=json.load(fid, strict=false);
```

or

import the hdf5 file using

```
import h5py
covid19=h5py.File('mydata.h5','r');
```

if the exported json file contains JData structures, you need to install **pyjdata** (https://pypi.org/project/jdata/) via

```
pip install jdata
```

and then load the .json file using

```
import jdata as jd
import numpy as np
newdata=jd.load('mydata.json')
```